# How to specify serviceAccount (created in default namespace) in the deployment yaml belonging to another namespace

Tags: kubernetes

I have created a serviceaccount(**dm-sa**) in the default namespace and used this serviceaccount in the clusterRole (bound to a PodSecurityPolicy) and clusterRoleBinding.
Next, in the deployment yaml(which will run in the namespace "dm"), I specified serviceAccount: dm and serviceAccountName: default under the template:spec. With this, kubernetes is searching for the **dm-sa** under the namespace **dm**, *instead* of looking under the **default** namespace. How to solve this. Please help.

template:
    spec:
      automountServiceAccountToken: true
      serviceAccount: dm-sa
      serviceAccountName: default

Comment: why not have the service account in the namespace of the deployment

Answer (score 1):

In general, when Kubernetes objects refer to each other, they need to be in the same namespace.  If a Deployment manages a Pod, and that refers to a ConfigMap, a Secret, a ServiceAccount, and a PersistentVolumeClaim, all of these things need to be in the same namespace.

I'd redeploy the service account in the target (`dm`) namespace.  You can delete the service account in the `default` namespace if you're not using it.

Comment: I used the serviceAccount in the default namespace because it allows me to execute some api's like `/api/v1/namespaces`, `/apis/apps/v1/deployments` . Otherwise, it errors out saying the serviceAccount does not have admin privileges

Comment: I got this problem solved. I followed these steps:
1. Created the service account dm-sa in the dm namespace.
2. Gave the privileges to use the api's in the ClusterRole file.
3. ClusterRole and Service account binding in the ClusterRoleBinding file.

Regarding the access to the api's, the list of api's that are intended to be used, need to be defined in the ClusterRole file.
With this, I was able to remove my dependence on the service account created inside the default namespace.